# Any way to programmatically parse all unknown type names in c++ header file?

Tags: python, c++, clang++

I have multiple header files containing valid c++ declarations for multiple classes, but there are no #include statements in these headers. I'm trying to find a way to programmatically parse all unknown types in these declarations so that I can generate some of the simple includes automatically and have a list of the types that still need to be defined. Also, if possible I would like to automate this using python. I have looked into using the clang parser and that somewhat works but it does not detect the unknown types and when reading through the AST it just replaces them with 'int'. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is an example of one of the header files:

```cpp
class Example : public Parent {
public:
    static const int DEFAULT_VALUE;

    static float exampleMethod(int);
    static std::vector<std::string> exampleMethodWithStl(const std::string&);
    Example(const std::string&, int, const AnotherType&);
};
```

I would like to parse this from the header file:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// unknown type name Parent
// unknown type name AnotherType

class Example : public Parent {
public:
    static const int DEFAULT_VALUE;

    static float exampleMethod(int);
    static std::vector<std::string> exampleMethodWithStl(const std::string&);
    Example(const std::string&, int, const AnotherType&);
};
```

Comment: The problem is not well-formed if you want exact results rather than just heuristics. Consider `class A : B { int x = X(); };`: `B` must be a type, but `X` may be a type or a function name or a variable name and depending on whether `B` has a member of name `X`, the question of whether `X` is undeclared changes. So, what exactly is your goal? Do you want all of these false-positives to be found?

Comment: @walnut I already know ahead of time there is not any actual implementations in the headers I have, only declarations. So in the case you presented I would only have: `class A : public B { int x; };`. My goal is to produce a list of all unknown type names, whether STL or otherwise. In the case of most of these types, they reference types defined in other headers in this same project, which I could generate an appropriate include to that file.

Comment: Your example has the same issue. Depending on the definition of `Parent`, `AnotherType` may or may not be undeclared. I just chose my example because it also demonstrates potential mismatch between types and non-types. If you have the appropriate definitions somewhere, you could of course include the required header once you find the first undeclared identifier and then restart parsing with it until you encounter the next undeclared identifier. My question is whether you really need such precise results or whether a heuristic would be enough.

Comment: If you want to have a somewhat decent result, you will need a full C++ parser because of the complex name lookup rules and context-sensitivity of the language, so using Clang as you mentioned is probably the best approach.

Comment: As for whether a type is declared in another file, that doesn't really matter. I really just need a list of what types are not declared in the current header.  As I mentioned in my post, when I used clang, it doesn't recognize the undeclared types and replaces them with `int`. For example, it prints the type of the constructor in the example to be: `void (const int&, int, const int&);`.  If anyone knows how to get clang to produce useful results, that would work.

Comment: There's a tool called `include-what-you-use` that does a decent job but it's more often used with `.cpp` files and tries to find what's missing or excessive from there. It requires some options to be of good use and sometimes suggest `C` headers (like `stdio.h`) when there's a standard `cstdio` that should be used instead. I think it brings just about enough value for me to keep it in the loop.

Comment: @walnut I just reread your message and I think I understand what you mean about the type being declared in the other file. My plan was to sort of do that manually.
So once I have the list of all unknown types I would for each type find the file it is declared in, and recursively run the same process for that header. Once the recursion for that file is complete, it would check if any of the remaining unknown types are defined in that file or a file it includes, etc, and skip it.